# Get Old Tweets on Twitter4j search

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to search an expression in Twitter, my code:

```
public static List<Status> searchQuery(Twitter twitter, String search)
        throws TwitterException, IOException {
    Query query = new Query(search);
    query.setCount(100);
    query.setSince("2015-05-25");
    QueryResult result;
    List<Status> tweets = null;
    do {
        System.out.println("Write to File ...");
        result = twitter.search(query);
        List<Status> newTweets = result.getTweets();
        if (tweets == null) {
            tweets = newTweets;
        } else {
            tweets.addAll(newTweets);
        }
        WriteToFile.writeTweetsToFile(newTweets);
    } while ((query = result.nextQuery()) != null);
    return tweets;
}
```

But it's just return tweets of last month, when I'm using `query.setUntil("2015-06-25");` nothing returned. What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have the right API key so that you can make those sorts of queries from that far back?

Comment: @Makoto I am generate API keys and Work correctly for last month tweets.

Comment: You can't get old tweets with the normal API key, you need be white labeled by twitter

Comment: @FeanDoe how become white labeled by twitter?

Comment: https://support.twitter.com/articles/160385#    (short answer, you need to be a partner. You could pay to services like https://gnip.com/sources/twitter/ )

Comment: Twitter API has some limitations, take a look at this library, it offers a solution to get old tweets: https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets

Answer (score 3):

I have developed a code to search for tweets wihtout this time restriction, you can look at [GitHub - GetOldTweets](https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets). It simple to use and you can search the deepest tweets.

Comment: I saw your code in GitHub. I want to get tweets by their id, how can I do this?